# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: items (in Dropdown List) ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have problem in my code. I'm using the registration form which comes with MVC5 , I added a field "Role" as a Dropdownlist to assign a role to the user while creating a new user. like in the below image:
[image]

Now in order to do that, I modified the "RegisterViewModel" and added the following properties:

```C#
        public IdentityRole Role { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Roles List")]
        public IEnumerable<IdentityRole> RolesList { get; set; }
```

In "AccountController", I changed the Register action, that gets the registration form, to become like this:

```C#
// GET: /Account/Register
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Register()
        {

            var _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
            var roles = _context.Roles.ToList();

            var viewModel = new RegisterViewModel
            {
                RolesList = roles
            };
            return View(viewModel);

        }
```

In the view "Register.cshtml" I added this Dropdownlist to load roles in the view and to post the role to the controller:

```C#
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Role.Id, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Role, new SelectList(Model.RolesList, "Name", "Name"), "Select Role", new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

in the Register controller, in the the registration form post, I added this

```C#
// POST: /Account/Register
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName , centerName = model.centerName };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    var role = new IdentityRole(model.Role.Name);

                    //I added this line to store the user and its roles in AspNetUserRoles table:
                    await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, role.Name);

                    await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    AddErrors(result);
                }
            }
```

Now when I try to register the user and post the form, I get following error:

```C#
Server Error in '/' Application.

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: items

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: items

Source Error: 


Line 41:         @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Role.Name, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
Line 42:         <div class="col-md-10">
Line 43:             @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Role, new SelectList(Model.RolesList, "Name", "Name"), "Select Role", new { @class = "form-control" })
Line 44:         </div>
Line 45:     </div>

Source File: c:..\TransactionsSystem\Views\Account\Register.cshtml    Line: 43
```

I tried different solutions to solve it, but nothing worked, can anybody please help or advise?

Comment: Make sure var roles = _context.Roles.ToList(); is returning values on all roles.

Comment: No, it doesn't duplicate anything, it is a specific problem in my code, not general question about what is the meaning of NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 14):

You cannot bind a `<select>` element to a complex object (which is what `Role` is) and when you submit the form, `ModelState` is invalid (your trying to bind the selected `Name` property of `RolesList` to typeof `IdentityRole`). You then return the view, but have not repopulated the `RolesList` property, so its `null` (hence the error).

View models should not contain data models, and you view model should be

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    ....
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a role")]
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RoleList { get; set; }
}
```

and in the GET method

```
var roles = _context.Roles.Select(r => r.Name);
var viewModel = new RegisterViewModel
{
    RolesList = new SelectList(roles)
};
return View(viewModel);
```

and in the view

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Role, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Role, Model.RolesList, "Select Role", new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

this will solve the invalid `ModelState` issue relating to `Role`, but if you do need to return the view because of other `ModelState` issues, then you must first repopulate the collection before returning the view

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var roles = _context.Roles.Select(r => r.Name);
    model.RolesList = new SelectList(roles);
    return View(model);
}
.... // save and redirect
```

Comment: I'm trying your solution, when I added (SelectListItem) to RegisterViewModel , I got this error, (The type or namespace name 'SelectListItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) so I imported the namespace (System.Web.Mvc) then I got new errors (Error 1 'CompareAttribute' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.CompareAttribute' and 'System.Web.Mvc.CompareAttribute') , (Error 2 The type or namespace name 'Compare' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?))

Comment: Now a new error (Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.WebPages.Html.SelectListItem>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?))

Comment: Your using the wrong references. You need to include both `System.Web.Mvc` and `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` but use the fully qualified name or alias - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36318044/compare-is-an-ambiguous-reference-between-system-componentmodel-dataannotatio)

Comment: What does it mean that "View models should not contain data models"? More clarification is necessary for this to be a useful answer.

Answer (score 3):

okay, i got the same problem, and none of the solution on this page helped me unless i figured it on my own.

while posting the form ,

when we use

```
If( ModelState.IsValid())
{
//post here


}

return view (model);
```

actually we are not initializing the items for dropdown list in the POST method. thats why this nullaugumentexception was thrown . we just need to initialize the list of items in the model inside the post method also as we did while calling the form, so that it can initialize the list if the model during the posting is not valid , and then
 put the model in return statement.

Comment: You have different problem, we are initializing the list, it is the common sense

Comment: @amal50 , you might have a different problem.  but mine was this one.. i had to initialize the list in post method also..so that in case the model is not valid, then the list must be initialized again to display in the form agian

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me in MVC5 for editing an existing user

Model (part of)

```
public IEnumerable<string> Roles { get; set; }
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserRole, new SelectList(Model.Roles, Model.UserRole), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Controller (Get)

```
 var model = new EditUserViewModel()
        {
            UserName = user.UserName,
            Email = user.Email,
            IsEnabled = user.IsEnabled,
            Id = user.Id,
            PhoneNumber = user.PhoneNumber,
            UserRole = userRoleName,

            // a list of all roles
            Roles = from r in RoleManager.Roles orderby r.Name select r.Name
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would create the select list in your controller and pass it to the model, writing something like

```
  var RolesList = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = string.Empty, Text = "Please select a Role..." }
            };

   RolesList.AddRange(roles.Select(t => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = t.role,
                Value = t.Id.ToString()
            }));`
```

and then add this to your model, in your model you can then use

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Role, Model.RoleList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

This method/syntax works for me I am not sure if It is 'best practice' though

Comment: it gives me new error, (The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'TransactionsSystem.Models.RegisterViewModel'.)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the list to the model before returning the view, or you will get this error.
Example:

cshtml:

```
@model DelegatePortal.ViewModels.ImpersonateVendorViewModel


@using (Html.BeginForm("ImpersonateVendor", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id, new SelectList(Model.Vendors, "Id", "Name"), "Choose a vendor", new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm " })
}
```

controller:

```
// GET: /Admin/ImpersonateVendor
    public ActionResult ImpersonateVendor()
    {
        ImpersonateVendorViewModel model = new ImpersonateVendorViewModel();
        var vendors = (from c in db.Vendors
                        select c).ToList();
        model.Vendors = vendors; --> add list here
        return View(model);
    }
```